# Partial template specialization for partial template parameter application not working GCC 4.8.1

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++11, partial-specialization

At the root of my policy-based class lies a container adapter that provides an interface for conversion between different containers. It is parametrized by a type T and template template parameter Container. In order to make it work with standard containers I need to partially apply some of their arguments, for example an allocator, or array size. This is how I do it:

```
template< typename T >
struct vector_{
  using policy = std::vector<T>; //default allocator
};
```

or in the case that's giving me trouble:

```
 //data_adapter expects template template parameter that takes one type-argument,
 //but sadly std::array is a template<typename, size_t>
 //so we need to partially apply the size_t parameter
namespace array_detail{
  template< size_t N >
  struct array_impl{
    template< typename T >
    using array_default = std::array<T, N>;
  };  //now we can write array_impl<32>::array_default which is template<typename T>
}
```

The problem is that I need to partially specialize `data_adaptor` for all N of `array_impl` and GCC 4.8.1 seems not to consider my specialization when calling its constructor. Here is the code:

data_adapter.hpp:

```
//data_adapter.hpp
#ifndef __DATA_ADAPTER_HPP__
#define __DATA_ADAPTER_HPP__

#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

template <
  typename T,
  template< typename t >
  class Container
> class data_adapter
: protected Container< T >
{
protected:
  typedef Container<T> data_type;

public:
    //constructor forwarding
  using data_type::data_type;

    //const iterator access for cross-container conversion copying
  using data_type::cbegin;
  using data_type::cend;

  data_adapter() = default;

public:
  ~data_adapter() {}
};

  //SFINAE helper to test whether T is an iterator or not

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct is_iterator
{
   static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_iterator<T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type, void>::value>::type>
{
   static constexpr bool value = true;
};

  //data_adapter expects template template parameter that takes one type-argument,
  //but sadly std::array is a template<typename, size_t>
  //so we need to partially apply the size_t parameter
namespace array_detail{
  template< size_t N >
  struct array_impl{
    template< typename T >
    using array_default = std::array<T, N>;
  };  //now we can write array_impl<32>::array_default which is template<typename T>
}

//partial specialization for array_impl<N>::array_default for any N???

template< typename T, size_t N >
class data_adapter< T, array_detail::array_impl<N>::template array_default >
: protected array_detail::array_impl<N>::template array_default<T>
{
protected:
  typedef typename array_detail::array_impl<N>::template array_default<T> data_type;

public:
  using data_type::data_type;

  using data_type::cbegin;
  using data_type::cend;

    //why doesn't std::array implement this constructor?
    //is it because it has static size and conversion from a dynamic container is dangerous?

  template<
    typename InputIt,
    typename = typename
      std::enable_if<is_iterator<InputIt>::value>::type
  > data_adapter( InputIt begin, InputIt end )
  : data_type() {
    std::copy( begin, end, this->begin() );
  }

public:
  ~data_adapter() {}
};

//still doesn't work with explicit instantiation
//template class data_adapter< int, array_detail::array_impl<32>::template array_default >;

#endif // __DATA_ADAPTER_HPP__
```

main.cpp:

```
//main.cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>


#include "data_adapter.hpp"

int main()
{
  std::mt19937 generator(time(NULL));
  std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned char> uniform_symbol( 0, 255 );
  auto random_symbol =
    [ &generator, &uniform_symbol ]( int ){
      return uniform_symbol(generator);
    };

  std::vector< int > symbols(32);
  std::transform( symbols.cbegin(), symbols.cend(), symbols.begin(), random_symbol );

  data_adapter< int, array_detail::array_impl<32>::template array_default > adapter( symbols.cbegin(), symbols.cend() );

  std::for_each( symbols.begin(), symbols.end(), []( int s ){ std::cout << s << " "; } );

  return 0;
}
```

errors:

```
g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions  -std=c++11 -g  -Wall    -c C:\Users\windows\Desktop\data_test\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
C:\Users\windows\Desktop\data_test\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\windows\Desktop\data_test\main.cpp:23:119: error: no matching function for call to 'data_adapter<int, array_detail::array_impl<32u>::array_default>::data_adapter(std::vector<int>::const_iterator, std::vector<int>::const_iterator)'
   data_adapter< int, array_detail::array_impl<32>::template array_default > adapter( symbols.cbegin(), symbols.cend() );
                                                                                                                       ^
C:\Users\windows\Desktop\data_test\main.cpp:23:119: note: candidates are:
In file included from C:\Users\windows\Desktop\data_test\main.cpp:9:0:
C:\Users\windows\Desktop\data_test\data_adapter.hpp:25:3: note: data_adapter<T, Container>::data_adapter() [with T = int; Container = array_detail::array_impl<32u>::array_default]
   data_adapter() = default;
   ^
C:\Users\windows\Desktop\data_test\data_adapter.hpp:25:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
C:\Users\windows\Desktop\data_test\data_adapter.hpp:11:9: note: constexpr data_adapter<int, array_detail::array_impl<32u>::array_default>::data_adapter(const data_adapter<int, array_detail::array_impl<32u>::array_default>&)
 > class data_adapter
         ^
```

It clearly does not consider the constructor I defined in the partial specialization for the array_impl, so the conclusion is that the data_adaptor in main.cpp instantiated the unspecialized version of the class. This is not a SFINAE problem, as the compiler would complain about lack of ::type in std::enable_if. Even, if I explicitly instantiate the specialized version, it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

---

EDIT:
Here is a minimal version that I think is equivalent:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<
  typename T,
  template < typename >
  class Container
> struct Foo{
  void test() const {
    std::cout << "Unspecialized Foo" << std::endl;
  }
};

template< size_t N >
struct array_{
  template< typename T >
  using policy = std::array<T, N>;
};

template<
  typename T, size_t N
> struct Foo< T, array_<N>::template policy >{
  void test() const {
    std::cout << "Foo< T, array<" << N << ">::policy >" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
    Foo< int, array_<10>::template policy > foo;
    foo.test();
    return 0;
}
```

Result at GCC 4.8.1:

```
Unspecialized Foo
```

Why is the unspecialized version called?

---

EDIT 2:
It seems to work when I write it this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<
  typename container
> struct Foo{
  void test() const {
    std::cout << "Unspecialized Foo" << std::endl;
  }
};

template<
  typename T, size_t N
> struct Foo< std::array<T, N> >{
  void test() const {
    std::cout << "Foo< std::array< T, " << N << ">" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
    Foo< std::array<int, 10> > foo;
    foo.test();
    return 0;
}
```

Looks like a GCC bug to me.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes That won't work for `std::array` which has an integer template argument (but it would solve the issue for `std::vector` etc. which all have additional template arguments beyond the value type).

Comment: "why doesn't std::array implement this constructor?" Because if it had a user-provided constructor then it would no longer be an aggregate and couldn't be initialized using aggregate initialization.

Comment: Considering that g++ and clang [agree on your original code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c01acd2c1e03df1e), I'm somewhat doubtful that this is a compiler bug.

Comment: I believe that g++'s behavior is correct. Partial specialization matching is done using template argument deduction, and anything to the left of `::` is a non-deduced context, which means that the compiler cannot deduce the `N` in your partial specialization, and hence the base template is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a compiler bug. §14.5.5.1 [temp.class.spec.match]/p1-2 specifies that

> When a class template is used in a context that requires an
>   instantiation of the class, it is necessary to determine whether the
>   instantiation is to be generated using the primary template or one of
>   the partial specializations. This is done by matching the template
>   arguments of the class template specialization with the template
>   argument lists of the partial specializations.
>
> - If exactly one matching specialization is found, the instantiation is generated from that specialization.
> - If more than one matching specialization is found, the partial order rules
>     (14.5.5.2) are used to determine whether one of the
>     specializations is more specialized than the others. If none of the
>     specializations is more specialized than all of the other matching
>     specializations, then the use of the class template is ambiguous and
>     the program is ill-formed.
> - If no matches are found, the instantiation is generated from the primary template.
>
> A partial specialization matches a given actual template argument list
>   if the template arguments of the partial specialization can be deduced
>   from the actual template argument list (14.8.2).

This uses the standard template argument deduction rules, and anything to the left of `::` (the technical term is the *nested-name-specifier* in a *qualified-id*) is a non-deduced context (§14.8.2.5 [temp.deduct.type]/p5), meaning that the compiler won't be able to deduce `N`; since deduction fails, the partial specialization is not a match, and the base template is used.

Comment: You sir, are a wizard. Thank you. I just used the rule you mentioned in an implicit_cast implementation!